# How to emulate a natural swipe in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-directive

All:

I am trying to use $swipe or ngSwipeLeft/Right, what I want to do is emulate a natural swipe like in Tinder or Okcupid:  If you fast swipe, it will lead to a remove of image, but if you slowly swipe, it still be able to cancel this swipe action?

Thanks